# Promtail ignores extraScrapeConfigs

Tags: kubernetes, grafana-loki

I've been making some tests with a Kubernetes cluster and I installed the loki-promtail stack by means of the helm loki/loki-stack chart.

The default configuration works fine, but now I would like to add some custom behaviour to the standard promtail config.

According to the [Promtail documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/pipelines/) I tried to customise the values.xml in this way:

```
promtail:        
   extraScrapeConfigs:
   - job_name: dlq-reader
     kubernetes_sd_configs:
     - role: pod
     pipeline_stages:
     - template:
         source: new_key
         template: 'test'
     - output: 
         source: new_key
```

The expected behaviour is that every log line is replaced by the static text "test" (of course this is a silly test just to get familiar with this environment).

What I see is that this configuration is correctly applied to the loki config-map but without any effect: the log lines looks exactly as if this additional configuration wasn't there.

The loki-stack chart version is 0.39.0 which installs loki 1.5.0.

I cannot see any error in the loki/promtails logs... Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered the issue then I post what I found in case this might help anyone else with the same issue.

In order to modify the log text or to add custom labels, the correct values.yaml section to provide is `pipelineStages` instead of `extraScrapeConfigs`. Then, the previous snippet must be changed in the following way:

```
 promtail:        
   pipelineStages:
   - docker: {}
   - match:
       selector: '{container="dlq-reader"}'
       stages:
       - template:
           source: new_key
           template: 'test'
       - output: 
           source: new_key
```

Comment: This is the only place where I could find an answer for this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems the config is in the wrong place. the [Docs](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/promtail/README.md#journald-support) says one should put this under `config.snippets.extraScrapeConfigs` , like this:

```yaml
promtail:
  config:
    snippets:
      extraScrapeConfigs: |
       # Add an additional scrape config for syslog
        - job_name: jobnamehere
          jobnamehere:
            yourconfighere.
```